# Cannot filter by status in a notion database using the notion js client

Tags: notion-api

I am trying to find all tasks in my database that do not have the completed status, but I get a "Could not find property with name or id: status" error.

my notion db

[image: 1]

```
(async () => {
  const databaseId = 'a secret';
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: databaseId,
    filter: {
      property: 'status',
      status: {
        does_not_equal: 'Completed'
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(response);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `property:'status'` to `property:'Status'`

```
(async () => {
  const databaseId = 'a secret';
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: databaseId,
    filter: {
      property: 'Status',
      status: {
        does_not_equal: 'Completed'
      }
    }
  });
  console.log(response);
})();
```